# I am looking for regex which returns false if it finds particular words anywhere in the paragraph in Java

Tags: regex

In our application we are allowing users to write HTML scripts and I don't want to save that script if it contains particular words like onmouseover, onclick etc.

E.g. if user enter script something like below then regex should return false. 
If it does not contain those words it should allow anything that user has entered.

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><b onclick="alert('Wufff!')">click me!</b></td>
        <td width="190"><b onmouseover="alert('Wufff!')">click me!</b></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I tried this regex and it did not work:

```
^(?=((?!onmouseover\s*=|onclick).)*$)(?=[\p{L}\p{P}\p{N}\p{So}\p{Sc}\s+%26&=&amp%\\\-_|<>/]+)$
```

Comment: Is `<p>onmouseover</p>` OK?

Comment: This isn't a good question. What strings exactly are you trying to match? Why is your regex so long, what were you trying to achieve? What do you mean "it did not work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use alternatives to check if those unwelcome words appear in the input text.

```
(?s)^((?!cellpadding|cellspacing|onmouseover).)*$
```

I guess this question is not about *parsing HTML*, only validating some input in a specific tool.

Comment: @Murthy: I updated the answer to match all strings (using `Singleline` option to also match newlines) that do not contain `cellpadding`, `cellspacing`, `onmouseover`. Looks like you are using PHP regex flavor, have a look at the demo: https://regex101.com/r/bQ7nL0/1

Comment: Yeah, that should work in Java, too. In JavaScript, it won't, since it does not support inline modifier `(?s)`.